# How to add inline animation in react?

Tags: css, reactjs

How can I add animations with keyframes **using** the prop `style` in react?

e.g.

```
<div
    style={{
        animation: 'how to add the animation with keyframes here?'
    }}
>
</div>
```

Comment: Inline styles do not support keyframes. There is a [hacky](https://gist.github.com/yamadayuki/f1ea9ccacad7f1c140457b5877fb54cc) way of doing it using `insertRule API`. But is always better to bind a css class which implements this animations to a conditional attribution and merge the styles together using string interpolation or `clsx` /`classnames` like libraries. Or even jss dynamic styles

Comment: Here, check out `styled-components`. This will do what you are looking for, plus the bonus benefit of using proper CSS. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43500934/5066625

Comment: `This will do what you are looking for` actually it does a different thing. The reason why I'm asking this question is because I'm coding in a legacy react project. That is why I'm trying to use it inline (everything in the project is inline)